# Displaying text within a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios6, uicollectionviewcell

I currently have implemented a UICollectionView with a UICollectionViewCell that does complete a segue when clicked. However, I want to display text within the UICollectionViewCell.

I'm wondering what the easiest way is to display only text within the UICollectionViewCell and to allow a segue to occur when the text is pressed (as opposed to running the segue from a blank UICollectionViewCell). I have tried using a TextView within the UICollectionViewCell but I had issue getting the segue to run when the TextView was pressed.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button with text.

Or add a `UITextView` and add a tap gesture recognizer to it with an action that performs the segue.

Comment: Remove the segue. And make another one from the button.

Comment: Try to set the title in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`. Therefore you have to store the string in a class property.

Comment: Check whether the `_currentProjects[index.row]` is not null.